# Configuring Content manager to use new database running in different machine

Tags: 2011, cme, database

Currently we have both Tridion and Content Manager database running on same machine.

We have a plan of creating a new database on another machine and linking the current Tridion CM to use new database.

Now I have question that can we run CM database and Tridion in two different machines. If yes how can we configure Tridion CM to use new database.

Please let me know your suggestions on this.

Currently we are using 2011 SP1 version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having a Tridion CM server connect to a CM DB on a different machine is a very common scenario. Also having multiple CM servers connect to the same CM DB is a supported architecture and we use this to scale out an implementation.

As to where you specify the CM DB - on your CM server, access the **SDL Tridion Content Manager configuration** link located in `Start button -> All Programs -> SDL Tridion`. This opens the **Tridion Content Manager** MMC.

Under node **Database settings** you can enter the connection details of the CM DB you want to use.

To make changes effective, you simply reboot the CM server (or if you want to take the long way round, restart all Tridion services, IIS, COM+).

Comment: Thank you For the answer. Actually we are upgrading our DB from 2008 R2 express version to Standard version. We would like to move all existing data to it. Definitely it would hep us.

Comment: You shuold be able to use a backup/restore of the Tridion database...